# Using MYSQL select from the sum of all posts made in a given week of the year with week starting Sunday

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am attempting to output a data table from MYSQL that displays all posts made on a Wordpress site, totaled by week of the year for the current year.

I would like to ensure that my query is counting weeks starting with the first Sunday of the year and each consecutive week beginning on the following Sunday.

I have managed to put together a functional query but I am quite new to MYSQL and I am unsure of syntax and how to modify it.

I am aware that YEARWEEK() allows for a mode to be selected that will identify the start day of the week ie SELECT YEARWEEK('2019-11-23', 0) AS 'Mode 0';

This sounds like exactly what I want to use, but I am not sure how to implement this given my current code (or if I already have).

```
SUM(if ( (WEEKOFYEAR(p.post_date) =  1), 1, 0)) as Wk1, 
SUM(if ( (WEEKOFYEAR(p.post_date) =  2), 1, 0)) as Wk2,
SUM(if ( (WEEKOFYEAR(p.post_date) =  3), 1, 0)) as Wk3,
(this repeats for each week)
```

The weekly totals generated by this query vary slightly from the offline tracking of the same data. I suspect it has something to do with how the start of the week is being calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might discover a way of making sure that the week count start from Sunday. You may want to try using `WEEK(date,mode)`. For example:

```
SUM(if ( (WEEK(p.post_date,0) =  1), 1, 0)) as Wk1, 
SUM(if ( (WEEK(p.post_date,0) =  2), 1, 0)) as Wk2,
SUM(if ( (WEEK(p.post_date,0) =  3), 1, 0)) as Wk3,
```

I've tested this with multiple dates starting from '2019-01-01' and it does count the week starting from the first Sunday of this year. So if the `post_date` is between '2019-01-01' to '2019-01-05' this year, it will identify as week 0 and only start identifying week 1 from '2019-01-06' onwards (which is the first Sunday of this year). More explanation about `WEEK()` function I refer to this link [MySQL 'WEEK()' Function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php)